# Ajax call (jquery) leaves the page user is on instead of holding same

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using jQuery (tried 1.x and 2.2 - same result) to make a simple GET call via Ajax from within an ASP.NET page.  I'm calling a CGI page on the same domain using SSL.  My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,

    headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 
    'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
    'Expires': '0'
},

url: "https://example.com/cgi-bin/start.exe/htmlPage.htm?infoBeingPassedToCgi=123"

error: function (data) {
    showMessageBox("ERROR", "ERROR", "An unexpected error occurred.  Please try again.");
    window.location.href = "https://example.com...";
},
success: function (data) {
    continue with stuff...
```

This has been what I've used for the past year or so and all was well.  Recently however, there's been an inconsistent result...

1. on one computer using Chrome and FF, the Ajax call works as intended, suspending the page while the program calls the CGI page behind the scenes.  Then continuing on the same page things resume for the user.  This is what I want.

On this same computer, using Edge (Win 10 64-bit), instead of staying where the page is, making the call and then continuing to stay on the same page... instead the page calls the CGI page and then transfers the user to a new html page with the results from the CGI call.  So the page is still calling the CGI, it executes and passes back the results, but instead of the originating Ajax page holding there, it just makes this new "output" page and shows the results in the top-left.

2. on another computer, the bad result (taking to new page of just Ajax call results) happens on Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

As you can see, there is inconsistency with the browser behavior across computers.

In my ASP.NET web.config page I'm doing this, but I don't think it's related as the original page and Ajax call page are both SSL on the exact same domain:

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Is this ajax related to a form submit or submit button event? Any errors in browser dev tools console before the expected ajax call?

Comment: There should be a comma at the end of the `url: ...` line.

Comment: Open the dev tools on a problem computer and set a breakpoint inside the `success` and `error` functions and see what happens. You can step through the javascript in the browser's dev tools.

Comment: 1.  There's 1 form on the page.  The ajax call is within that form.  This being ASP.NET, I've also used an UpdatePanel.  So essentially I have a multi-step form and during the steps there is a "coupon code" field with an ajax button next to it to go "check the code", but keep user on same page and step in the form.

Comment: 1.  There's 1 form on the page.  The ajax call is within that form.  This being ASP.NET, I've also used an UpdatePanel.  So essentially I have a multi-step form and during the steps there is a "coupon code" field with an ajax button next to it to go "check the code", but keep user on same page and step in the form.

Comment: 2.  There is a comma, sorry.  I just edited/shortened the URL line call for posting here.  There's a comma and if there weren't, I suppose none of the computers/browsers would perform the call successfully.

Comment: 3.  I'm not seeing an error, just a warning in Edge:

HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace.

In the instances where this process does NOT work... when I click the ajax button, I get a pop-up of mine (under the ajax error setting)., but instead of showing a message like "10% off", it has "undefined".

Then I'm taken to the "blank" page, with this text on it (which comes from my CGI page:

|ERROR|INVALID OFFER CODE:  asdf

("asdf" was my test code).  This is the correct result and I parse that when it comes back to ajax call.

Comment: I am getting something in the Edge debug tools:

SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.
polyfill (1,10884)

CSS3121: The media query -ms-viewport has been deprecated.

HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace.
myAspnetPage (601,15)

Comment: How does one put in a line break here?